# Correct syntax for mysql JSON path to traverse arrays?

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

My question is about searching through the contents of json arrays when searching in mysql's JSON data type.

#### DB Structure

So, if i have two rows in a mysql table, with a json field, called `foo`.

The first row has:

```
{
  "items": [
    {"type": "bar"}
  ]
}
```

The second row has:

```
{
  "items": [
    {"type": "baz"}
  ]
}
```

#### Things that work

I can run

```
select `foo`->"$.items[0].type" from `jsontest`
```

to return 2 results: `bar` and `baz`

I can run

```
select `id` from `jsontest` where `foo`->"$.items[0].type" = "bar"
```

to return 1 result: `1` - ie. the id of the first row.

#### My Problem

The [mysql docs state](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html#json-paths) that you can use `[*]` to "evaluate to the values of all elements in a JSON array".

However, the following query returns zero items:

```
select `id` from `jsontest` where `foo`->"$.items[*].type" = "bar"
```

What is wrong with my query?

Answer (score 10):

Make the following query:

```
select id, `foo`->"$.items[*].type[0]" from `jsontest`;
```

You'll notice returned value is displayed as "[bar]", which is JSON array.

```
select * from `jsontest` 
where `foo`->"$.items[*].type" = JSON_ARRAY('bar');
```

Anyway, the following query should work too:

```
select id from `jsontest` where JSON_SEARCH(`foo`, 'all','bar') is not null;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```sql
SELECT `id` FROM `jsontest` WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(`foo`->"$.items[*].type", '"bar"', '$')
```